# Html DropDownListFor asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Could some please convert the following code to a standard html tag? Something like `<select id="selectDomain" name="selectDomain">`, IF it converts to a select tag.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.domain, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "", new { id = "selectDomain", name = "selectDomain"})
```

If I understand correctly, doesn't `x => x.domain` mean `id="domain" name="domain"`? Is this code overwriting the `name` and `id` to `selectDomain`?

Finally, if it isn't convertible to an html tag, I want to add a class to the given code. I tried adding it inside the `new{}` like `new{id="selectDomain", name="selectDomain", class="form-control"}` section but it gave me error saying `expected }`

Comment: If you want to add a class attribute, you will need to use the '@' before 'class' because class is a reserved word: `new{id="selectDomain", name="selectDomain", @class="form-control"}`

Comment: Why don't you run application and view source in browser?

Comment: @ElConrado haha am i really that dumb? doesn't really make much sense with all the attributes but I got it, thanks :P

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti yes, that did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand correctly if you write:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.domain, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
```

Razor will produce:

```
<select id="domain" name="domain"> </select>
```

It's better to use ViewModel and create property `selectDomain` in it and then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectDomain, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class="form-control" })
```

Will make html that you want.

But if you don't want to do it you can use `Html.DropDownList` helper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectDomain",Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class="form-control" })
```

note escaped `class` with `@` symbol.

Comment: I like the approach using viewmodel it makes the code more readable

Comment: @FedriQrueger yeap, that's clean MVC way

Comment: I have a ViewModel with domain as the property

Comment: @BivoKasaju Razor helpers uses your property name as `name` and `id`  tag attributes value. So you should change property name if you want different output. Or just use DropDownList helper where you can pass name as param.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify "name" with uppercase first letter (works in MVC5)

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.domain, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "", new { id = "selectDomain", Name = "selectDomain"})
```

result:

```
  <select name="selectDomain" id="selectDomain">
```

Comment: Never do this! It will ensure that model binding fails.